# jRTF cannot write template to file

Tags: java, groovy, frameworks

my goal is to create an expose using a rtf template and fill the variables in with custom properties. For this I am using [jRTF](http://www.tutego.de/blog/javainsel/2010/07/jrtf-a-new-library-for-building-rtf-documents/) and programming in groovy.

In the documentation you can see that the output is performed with this code:

```html
Rtf.template( new FileInputStream("template.rtf) )
   .inject( "ADDRESSLINE1", "tutego" )
   .inject( "ADDRESSLINE2", bold("Sonsbeck") )
   .out( FileOutputStream("out.rtf") );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. My code looks like this:

```html
def createExpose() {
    def template = Rtf.template(new FileInputStream("C:\\template.rtf")).inject( "PERSON", "John Smith" )
    .inject( "BIRTHDATE", "1992" )
    .inject( "LOCATION", "Milky Way" )
    .inject( "CITIZENSHIP", "Mars" ).out(FileOutputStream("out.rtf"))

    def response = template
    return response
}
```

It works if i just use out() without a parameter, but I only get the Byte String which still needs to be converted to a rtf file. Anyone have an idea?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the problem lies in the fact that you're missing a "new" before FileOutputStream.  Simple mistake, could happen to anyone.  ;)